# Asp.Net Get Control Values from PlaceHolder

Tags: c#, foreach, placeholder

I have defined a placeholder in my page like this;

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="attrPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

I am populating this place holder from a database table using query string productId like this;

```
 // obtain the attributes of the product
                DataTable attrTable = CatalogAccess.GetProductAttributes(productId);
                // temp variables
                string prevAttributeName = "";
                string attributeName, attributeValue, attributeValueId;
                // current DropDown for attribute values
                Label attributeNameLabel;
                DropDownList attributeValuesDropDown = new DropDownList();
                // read the list of attributes
                foreach (DataRow r in attrTable.Rows)
                {
                    // get attribute data
                    attributeName = r["AttributeName"].ToString();
                    attributeValue = r["AttributeValue"].ToString();
                    attributeValueId = r["AttributeValueID"].ToString();
                    // if starting a new attribute (e.g. Color, Size)
                    if (attributeName != prevAttributeName)
                    {
                        prevAttributeName = attributeName;
                        attributeNameLabel = new Label();
                        attributeNameLabel.Text = "<li class=\"txt\">" + attributeName + ":</li>";
                        attributeValuesDropDown = new DropDownList();
                        attrPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(attributeNameLabel);
                        attrPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(attributeValuesDropDown);
                    }
                    // add a new attribute value to the DropDownList
                    attributeValuesDropDown.Items.Add(new ListItem(attributeValue, attributeValueId));
                }
```

However, when inside a button click event, when I loop through this place using visual studio debugging, I saw that the visual studio studio debugger first hit the "**attrPlaceHolder.Controls"** word in my foreach loop, then secondly comes to '**in'** keyword (in foreach loop) but it isn't hitting the first two words (i-e **'Control cnt'** in my foreach loop. Here it looks;

```
protected void ButtonBuyNow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Retrieve the selected product options
    string options = "";
    foreach (Control cnt in attrPlaceHolder.Controls)
    {
        if (cnt is Label)
        {
            Label attrLabel = (Label)cnt;
            options += attrLabel.Text;
        }

        if (cnt is DropDownList)
        {
            DropDownList attrDropDown = (DropDownList)cnt;
            options += attrDropDown.Items[attrDropDown.SelectedIndex] + "; ";
        }
    }

    // Add the product to the shopping cart
    ShoppingCartAccess.AddItem(productId, options);
}
```

Basically I need 'options' variable to be populated but it isn't hitting the foreach loop inside, therefore I am not able to get the 'options' variable populated.
This is a serious problem in my application. Please tell me **why I can't get the inside the foreach loop**.

**NOTE:**
please note that this isn't the complete code of my entire page. My rest of the code executes correctly.

Comment: Have You checked if Controls.Count > 0 ? If debbugger hits Controls, but is not going inside loop, it means that collection is empty.

Comment: The first code snippet, where you create the controls. Where do you call it, at Page_Load? Are there any conditions (like postback)? Controls dynamically created must be re-created at Page_Init, so the Page Lifecycle can bind the viewstate to them. You're not entering the foreach because the list is empty.

Comment: yes, I did that now, the condition is executing false. But I don't know why, because I am getting the values i-e dropdownList and label control inside the placeholder on front page.

Comment: thanks for reminding me to check before actually calling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why I can't get the inside the foreach loop

Because the list is empty.

> Why is the list empty? (Would be the next logical question)

Because, at ASP.Net, dynamically created controls must be re-created at `Page_Init` in order to *exist*. When you create them at this stage, the **page lifecycle** will bind the viewstate and will be ready for use.
If you receive a postback (from the button, for example) and don't recreate them, they simply don't exist.

Comment: you answer does have a point. let me try it, I will response to you back soon.

Comment: haaha. love you logic man. it worked. I just moved my code to Page_Init event and it works. I don't have words to thank you. God bless you.